# Make event happen every nth time

Tags: c#, audio

I'm trying to create a camera that's responsive to live audio input.  Right now the way my code is written, the camera changes to a random animation every single time the audio input crosses a specified amplitude threshold.

The amplitude threshold is a value between 0 and 1 coming from AudioPeer._audioBand (my input)

What I want is for the camera to change positions every Nth time the audio crosses that threshold, instead of every single time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to C# Thanks!

```
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}


void Update()
{

            if (AudioPeer._audioBand[_band] > .7)
            {
                int randomNumber = Random.Range(1, 4);
                anim.Play("cam" + randomNumber);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should definitely add the unity tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 'nth' time is easy to simiulate with a simple counter, either reset the counter when the `n` value is reached or use a modulus of the counter to determine when to act:

```
/// <summary>the number of iterations when to act</summary>
private const int n = 7;
/// <summary> member level counter, to track how many times Update() has been called </summary>
private int counter = 0;

void Start()
{
    counter = 7; // reset the counter, but make sure the first time runs.
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (AudioPeer._audioBand[_band] > .7)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= n)
        {
            // reset the counter
            counter = 0;
             
            // Execute your logic
            int randomNumber = Random.Range(1, 4);
            anim.Play("cam" + randomNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

> Using `if (counter % n == 0)` would be simpler, however the value of `n` might get very large over time and could eventually overflow, so in a long running scenario (which audio processing can easily evolve into) it is better to us a reset pattern.

Comment: this makes sense! although when I plug it in, I get an error at             // reset the counter
            n = 0;  that says "the left hand assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"

Comment: Yes well you have to declare the `counter` and `n` variables in the member scope outside the `Update` method, so in the same class, just outside the method, something like  `private int counter = 0;`

Comment: Sorry @MaxSolomon that was a typo, we need to reset the counter, thats why I declared the `n` variable as a const.

Answer (score 0):

Just can just increment the occurrence and use the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators)

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its
> left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.

```
private int _count;
private int _someAmount = 3;

...


if (unchecked(_count++ % _someAmount == 0))
{
      // change camera
}
```

<sub>***Note** [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) suppresses overflow-checking and will **not** overflow*</sub>